# I can not send email from self package laravel - wrong template path

Tags: php, laravel, email, package

I am trying to make Laravel package which will send an email.
There is my folder structure after publish package
http://prntscr.com/nbddef
As you see I have template there
But when I try to send a mail I receive this exception:

```
 #message: "View [D:\OSPanel\domains\testPackage.loc\app.Widgets.views.template] not found."
```

I was trying to change this template path in my code but it doesnt help

```
<?php
namespace Imediasun\Widgets\Mail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer as MailerContract;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
class OrderSend extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $order;
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->sub='New Csv Import Received';
        $this->recipient='imediasun@gmail.com';
        $this->sender=['address'=>'imediasu1n@gmail.com','name'=>'Andrey'];
        $this->template=app_path() .'/Widgets/views/template';
        $this->exception=false;
    }
    public function build()
    {
            return $this->from($this->sender)->to($this->recipient)->subject($this->sub)->view($this->template);
    }


}
```

Comment: try this
app_path('Widgets/views/template');

Comment: Same result sorry View [D:\OSPanel\domains\testPackage.loc\app\Widgets.views.template] not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a contractor you need to do such

```
$this->template='Widgets::template';
```